# TFS - assert fail messages

Tags: unit-testing, tfs

When I develop a TFS test case, automate it as a "unit test" (test method) and execute from TFS "Run Functional Tests" step, I see the test case become passed or failed. When it become "failed", I cannot see where it went wrong. I cannot see the assert failed messages, or the exception was thrown unexpectedly, or something.

How should I know the reason of failed? 
Where can I see the reason? In which log? 
Is there any log?

Comment: I see when I double-click on test case history an "error message" part with Stack Trace. May it is the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the **Stack Trace** is the answer. Debug the tests based on the messages.

You can get the reason from the test results report (`Detailed report >`):

Build Summary --> Test Results --> Click the `Detailed report >` link --> Navigate to the specific failed test to check the **Stack trace**

[image]

Comment: @Zoltan Hernyak We can only get the reason from the Stack trace, no details in test log. Have you resolved the issue by the confimation above?Any update?